# Совершенный и несовершенный виды глагола

Tags: грамматика

Когда следует употреблять совершенный или несовершенный вид глагола, изменяется ли смысл предложения при неправильном применении этих видов? Возможно ли в одном сложном предложении применение обоих видов глагола?

Answer (score 1):

**Категория вида - важнейшая характеристика глагола**, любой глагол относится к совершенному или несовершенному действию. Категория вида дополняет категорию времени в части обозначения завершенности действия. Фактически с учетом вида мы имеем не три, а пять форм времени.

Поэтому вид глагола выбирается **в соответствии с действием, которое требуется обозначить,** неверное употребление вида не допускается, в одном предложении могут быть глаголы разного вида, например: К обеду **добрался** я до вершины, **оглянулся** и долго **искал** избушку, которая **спряталась** в заснежённой тайге. [Юрий Коваль. Белозубка (1979)]

**Для справок**

**1)  Глаголы несовершенного вида** обозначают длительное (незаконченное)  действие и отвечают на вопросы что делать, что делает, что будет делать – например: читать, читает, читал, будет читать, то есть глаголы несовершенного вида могут употребляться в   неопределенной форме и в формах настоящего, прошедшего и будущего сложного времени.Таким образом, несовершенный вид глагола соотносится **с тремя формами  времени**.

**Б) Глаголы совершенного вида** обозначают законченное действие и отвечают на вопросы что сделать, что сделает, что сделал –  например: прочитать, прочитает, прочитал, то есть глаголы совершенного вида могут употребляться в  неопределенной форме и в формах прошедшего и простого будущего времени.

Таким образом, совершенный вид глагола соотносится **с двумя формами  времени**.

Answer (score 1):

Я попробую объяснить как для человека, у которого русский не родной. 
Русскоязычного я бы просто отправила читать учебники.

> Когда следует употреблять совершенный или несовершенный вид глагола,

Совершенный и несовершенный вид глагола в русском - близкий аналог перфекта и имперфекта в английском и других европейских языках. Есть некоторые отличия, но это тонкости. Эти две глагольные формы когда-то существовали и в русском, но со временем исчезли. В качестве некоторой замены им и появилось разделение глаголов на совершенный и несовершенный вид.

Особенно это важно понимать для прошедшего времени глаголов.
делал-сделал, убегал-убежал, играл-сыграл. 
Оба глагола в паре означают действие в прошлом, но если первый означает действие никаким результатом не законченное или не доведенное до конца либо неоднократно повторяемое, то второй - действие законченное и как правило результативное.

Принципиальным является то, что в английском перфект и имперфект - это вид одного глагола, то в русском - это **разные** глаголы, обычно с одним корнем, но разными суффиксами и приставкой, поэтому и значения у них могут быть немного разными не только в части перфектности.

> изменяется ли смысл предложения при неправильном применении этих
>   видов?

Да, как правило так и происходит, смысл меняется, примеры - выше. Хотя в некоторых случаях эти различия несущественны для понимания. 
"Я спал пять часов" и "я поспал пять часов" - разницы в значениях почти нет.

> Возможно ли в одном сложном предложении применение обоих видов глагола?

Да, возможно. В русском языке вообще почти нет грамматических ограничений на использование разных видовременных форм глаголов в одном предложении. Важно только следить, чтобы не получилась бессмыслица.

Answer (score 0):

Совершенный вид:
1) нам важен результат действия
 Я прочитал книгу
Несовершенный вид:
1) просто действие, результат которого нам не важен
Я читала книгу
2) процесс действия
Я читал книгу весь вечер
(Со словами весь+промежуток времени)
3) повторяемое действие
Я читала эту книгу каждый день.

Конечно, возможно примение двух видов.
Я читала эту книгу каждый день, а сегодня, наконец, прочитала её.
Пока я спала, мама приготовила завтрак.

Comment: Что-то все нужные знаки в первом абзаце у вас посыпались.

Comment: Я писала с телефона и тоже заметила, но суть, я думаю, ясна

Comment: Здесь разговоры не на бегу, если Вы обратили внимание. Это не Скорая помощь, это сайт на русском языке и о нём. Суть, я думаю, ясна? ( Есть кнопка Править!).

Answer (score -2):

В самом русском языке нету такого вида глагола - несовершенный. Оно есть в общественности 
Виды глаголов. Есть источники от общественности, в которых люди честно признают: *"Однако до сих пор нет единства мнений по вопросу об определении семантики вида, о различии между совершенным и несовершенным видом"*. Несостыковки происходят потому, что одни знатоки утверждают, что совершенный вид определяется предельным (завершённым) действием; а другие − непредельным (незавершённым) действием. 
       Допустим, что совершенный вид определяется завершённым действием, но тогда у него не может быть будущего времени. Допустим, что несовершенный вид определяется незавершённым действием, тогда у него не может быть прошедшего времени. И наоборот. 
       Путаница с видами идёт от неразличения действия (как понятия). 
       Глаголом обозначается действие. Действие определяется по известным, законченным, состоявщимся признакам, то есть действие уже − предел. Видом глагола обозначается вид действия (опредёлённый предел). Действие само по себе предельно, и вид говорит не о пределе предельного (о пределе действия, которое предельно), а о неких других признаках действия. 
       Рассмотрим отвлечённый пример, чтобы потом сопоставить с ним виды глаголов. Два вопроса: 
       1. Какого вида эта рыба (к какому виду принадлежит карп)? Ответ − карповые. 
       2. В каком виде эта рыба (каково состояние карпа)? Ответ − рыба живая. 
       Отличный пример, из которого видно, что "вид" можно понимать по-разному. 
       Глаголом обозначается действие (действие целостно; нету целостности − действия не определить). Вид глагола говорит о виде определённого действия. 
Переносим пример с карпом на виды глаголов: 
       1. Какого вида может быть действие (сопоставляем с "какого вида эта рыба?")? 
       2. В каком виде может быть действие (сопоставляем с "в каком виде эта рыба?")? 
       Вот они два вида. Смотрим их с временами глаголов: 
       1. Какого вида может быть действие? Ответ − совершенного (от совершение). 
       Совершенный вид говорит о: 
       а) действие удалось совершить (действие получилось; выполнение действия состоялось) − прошедшее время, отвечает на вопрос: "что сделал?". 
       б) совершение действия намечается (действие может произойти позже) − будущее время, отвечает на вопрос: "что сделаю?". 
       2. В каком виде может быть действие? Ответ − продолженном (а не в несовершенном). 
       Продолженный вид говорит о: 
       а) действие выполняется в данное время − настоящее время, отвечает на вопрос: "что делаю?". 
       б) действие продолжалось какое-то время (было такое) − истекшее время, отвечает на вопрос: "что делал?".