# Совершенный и несовершенный вид глагола в одном предложении

Tags: глаголы

Можно ли употреблять в одном предложении глаголы разных видов? 
Например: 
"Заболела голова, сердце тяжело билось в груди".
И если да, то есть ли правило, которое это регламентирует?

Comment: Можно посмотреть здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427680/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0 (Совершенный и несовершенный виды глагола).

Answer (score 1):

***Заболела голова, сердце тяжело билось в груди.***

Глаголы разного вида могут употребляться в одном предложении. Вид глаголов определяется тем действием, которое они обозначают, и **соответствием** этих действий для данного предложения.

***Заболела*** (сов. вид) — приставка ЗА обозначает начало действия, которое затем продолжается,  то есть заболела (начала болеть) и болит **сейчас**.

***Билось***  (несов. вид) — действие также происходит **в данный момент.**

Семантика и грамматика соответствуют друг другу.

Comment: Такое вполне может быть. Но в этом предложении такое не звучит. Смысл в том, что "резко заболела голова". А предложение описывает один момент, в котором оба действия происходят одинаково. Можно добавить "уже" к второй части, что действие началось ранее (и поэтому несовершенная форма). Если описывать какой-то день, то "заболела" не подходит.

Comment: Ваши фантазии и причудливый ход мыслей, возможно, кого-то и могут заинтересовать, но почему вы рассказываете всё это мне? Дайте свой ответ и научите автора правильно выбирать вид глагола.

Comment: Просто контекст представьте: кому и когда так можно сказать. А вы тут просто грамматически ответили.

Comment: А вы тогда что здесь будете делать,  если я за вас всё представлю и расскажу?

Comment: Прочитаю и, возможно, стану умнее от этого)))

Comment: Я почему-то считала, что у меня на этом форуме несколько другие задачи.

Comment: Разве не делать умнее других? Не просветление?

Comment: Вы лучше у модераторов узнайте. Может быть, у меня здесь особая миссия, а я и не знаю.

Comment: Вы рассмотрели грамматику, но спрашивалось явно про стилистику. Одно действие началось в какой-то момент, а другое уже было и до этого, но об этом не сказано. Так не звучит. Хорошо добавить "*и при этом*". Или это те вещи, которые происходили сегодня в общем. Но тогда приставка *за-* не употребляется.